# Can I call a Stored Procedure from an EntityDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

(ASP.net 3.5, C#, SQL Express 2008)

I want to have a Web Form, where I can search for "Solutions" (my table) using a keyword entered by the user and after the result comes back and populates a GridView.

I already have parts of this search via a stored procedure that is hooked up to my Entity Data Model. On this page I have an EntityDataSource. **How can I make this EntityDataSource grab data from my stored procedure?**

I realize I could just fetch the result via the Entity context (which works), and bind it to the grid, but if I don't hook it up to the EntityDataSource I won't get automatic paging and sorting (which has been another struggle of mine in the past)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `Function Import`.

1. Right click on the EntitySet Name (the heading part)
2. Choose Add->Function Import

Here is a good blog post for you to check out. [ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools: Stored Procedures, by Guy Burstein](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/12/17/ado-net-entity-framework-tools-stored-procedures.aspx)

**Update:**  Sorry I missed the part about the `EntityDataSource` so I don't know of any property exposed to access a function import from the EDS, but your can try to use the CommandText property.

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="SolutionsDataSource" runat="server" 
    CommandText="DataModel.SearchFunction(@Keywords)"
    ConnectionString="name=AdventureWorksEntities">
    <CommandParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Keywords" 
            ControlID="SearchTextbox" Type="String"/>
    </CommandParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

**Update:**  Well it seems that I have some bad news.  After using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to dive deep into the `EntityDataSource`.  The `EntityDataSourceView` is constructed using `QueryBuilderUtils.ConstructQuery`, which then in turn calls `context.CreateQuery<T>`.  What you would need to execute the function import is a call to `context.ExecuteFunction<T>`.  There doesn't seem to be any support for the ExecuteFunction in this release, the blogs I was reading did mention that it was planned, but it didn't make it into this release, whether or not it will be in future releases I can't say.

That being said I would recommend using an `ObjectDataSource`, which you can construct in a way that still supports paging, sorting, etc.  If you open an ObjectDataSource question on this topic send me a comment here and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I read it through, and this I have. I can search via my SP, I just miss the part where I can bind that up to the GridView I have, via an EntityDataSource (if possible).

Comment: I tried to add the function to the CommandText, but it won't work. Landing on the error "The EntitySet 'SearchSolutions' is not defined in the EntityContainer 'solutioncottageEntities'., near multipart identifier."

Comment: Try using DataModel.SearchFunction(@Keywords) for your CommandText.

Comment: Next error message: 'solutioncottageModel.SearchSolutions' cannot be resolved into a valid type constructor or function., near function, method or type constructor, line 1, column 37.
Using: CommandText="solutioncottageModel.SearchSolutions(@SearchString)"

Comment: I was using an ObjectDataSource together with a DataSet previously but was looking into switching to the Entity framework. Maybe there are better ways to accomplish what I'm doing here, but that's another question. I'll accept this as the answer and thanks for your extended research!

Comment: so this was a year ago, i don't see a way of doing it now either.  Attempting the objectDataSource, but I think I will have to add the function to the data class...

Comment: Has there been any movement on this in EF5 or EF6? anyone?